# How to use forward ref in class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

//How to use this inside a class component.
//Below code is written for functional component

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  // textInput must be declared here so the ref can refer to it
  const textInput = useRef(null);
  
  function handleClick() {
    textInput.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={textInput} />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can't use hooks in class component they are designed to be used in functional component in class components you can just use `state` and `this.setState` instead, so for you code the class version would be:

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  textInput = null

  handleClick = () => {
    this.textInput.focus()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={(ref) => (this.textInput = ref)} />
        <input type="button" value="Focus the text input" onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

or

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  textInput = React.createRef()

  handleClick = () => {
    this.textInput.current.focus()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={this.textInput} />
        <input type="button" value="Focus the text input" onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

version with constructor

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  textInput

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.textInput = React.createRef()
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.textInput.current.focus()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={this.textInput} />
        <input type="button" value="Focus the text input" onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How to use forward ref in class component for the above functional component. @Evgeny Klimenchenko

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: textInput = React.createRef()  can we declare this line inside a constructor??

Comment: yes, like this,`this.textInput = React.createRef() `

Comment: Yes, you can or you can do it like I did

Comment: I added the version with constructor, if you prefer this way

Comment: error    Arrow function should not return assignment  no-return-assign                                getting this error..   ---->  ref={(ref) => (this.titleRef = ref)}

Comment: That is a rule you have in your ESlint

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

In Class Component Form,

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
    textInput = React.createRef()

    handleClick = () => {
        this.textInput.current.focus()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" ref={this.textInput} />
                <input
                    type="button"
                    value="Focus the text input"
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

With Constructor,

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
       super()
       this.textInput = React.createRef()
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.textInput.current.focus()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" ref={this.textInput} />
                <input
                    type="button"
                    value="Focus the text input"
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```